# DRF serializer do not return a value with extra_kwargs of write_only

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm practicaly copying the exemple code from the documentation, but the password field, with "extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}" is not returned as validated data.

this is the code:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = models.UserProfile
    fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birthday', 'gender', 'telephone', 'password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = models.UserProfile(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        birthday=validated_data['birthday'],
        gender=validated_data['gender'],
        telephone=validated_data['telephone']
    )

    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()

    return user
```

Take a look at the local variables. "password" is passed to the initialization function but do not return as validated_data

self:

```
UserProfileSerializer(data={'email': 'magalhaes@magalhaes.com', 'first_name': 'eduardo', 'last_name': 'magal', 'birthday': None, 'gender': None, 'telephone': '123465', **'password': 123456**}):
    email = EmailField(max_length=255, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())>])
    first_name = CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=64)
    birthday = DateField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    gender = ChoiceField(allow_null=True, choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Outro')), required=False)
    telephone = CharField(allow_null=True, max_length=50, required=False)
    password = CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
```

validated_data:

```
{'birthday': None,
 'email': 'magalhaes@magalhaes.com',
 'first_name': 'eduardo',
 'gender': None,
 'last_name': 'magal',
 'telephone': '123465'}  **No password...**
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you add UserProfile model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
if user_serializer.is_valid():
   user_serializer.save()
else:
   print(user_serializer.errors)
```

then you will know why you password is not vaild.